# Yellowish pattern on leafs of tomato seedlings

Tags: tomatoes

My tomato seedlings are experiencing discolouration on the leaves. I am unsure of what this could be. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you been fertilizing them with?

Comment: nothing. they were planted in potting soil which should be fertilezed by manufacturer.

Comment: Is there anything underneath the affected leaves that shouldn't be there?

Comment: nope, they look good.

Comment: small pot, large plant [but we do not see well the pots]

Comment: the pot is the same size as previous years. This is the first time I am observing this issue. I've added Mg fertilizer foliarly. Would you do the same?

Comment: Your plant needs a bit more fertilizer added. Potting soil with added fertilizer is very generic and will soon be used up by tomato plants.  Mg is not a balanced fertilizer.  You need a fertilizer with NPK, make sure the N is lower in percentage than the P and the K.  Or at the very least equal.  You need to add a simple balanced fertilizer (this is NOT PLANT FOOD)...Osmocote, 14-14-14 is extended release and hard to misuse.  Soil, any soil, potting soil or soil in the garden, should never be assumed to have the necessary chemistry plants need to make their own food via sunlight.

Comment: Manganese deficiency?

Comment: ou wow. Mn deficiency symptoms look even more similar to what I have than Mg deficiency. And yes, I have overestimated the commercial potting soil. It didn't even last 6 weeks before deficiencies start to show up.